# useQuery parameter dependent on data from another useQuery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have the following `useQuery` function

```
const useQueryBlob = (url: string) => {
  return useQuery<Blob>(
    'blob',
    async () => {
      const { data: blob } = await axios.get<Blob>(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
      return blob;
    },
  );
};
```

The `url` I want to pass is someData from `useQueryTest`

```
  const { data: someData } = useQueryTest('test');
  const { data: blob } = useQueryBlob(someData);
```

However, `someData` is always `undefined` on the first render so the `url` passed to `useQueryBlob` is also `undefined`.

How do I make sure that the `url` passed to `useQueryBlob` is not `undefined` on the first render?

Comment: Check, if it is undefined and only call `userQueryBlob(someData)`, when it isn't.

Comment: check this [doc](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/dependent-queries) you can set `enable` property to false or dependent to `someData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `enabled` boolean. This will disable the query from automatically running until the enabled is set to `true`.

See [useQuery docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery) and [Dependent Queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries).

```js
const useQueryBlob = (url: string | undefined) => {
  return useQuery<Blob>(
    'blob',
    async () => {
      const { data: blob } = await axios.get<Blob>(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
      return blob;
    },
    { enabled: !!url }
  );
};
```